# How can I port all my images to imgur to prevent bad images across the network?

Tags: images

I thought my image host was always up and did have enough bandwidth to support my images, most of my images are screenshots I took with a tool. Now apparently I've got a mail that I'm reaching the bandwidth limit for free users, which means that if I continue to use the tool like this I will simply get out of bandwidth and a lot of my answers will then just show broken images.

Other than that, I eventually have infrequently used a link that points to an external source.

It would be handy if I could port my images to imgur in order to prevent this problem.

How do I go about and do this in an automatized manner? Perhaps this can be interesting as a solution?

If there is no automation possible or if it is prohibited, how do I form a Data Exchange query to find images?

Comment: This is totally a Meta question - seems weird to be migrated here.  It doesn't make sense as a webmasters question at all, to me.

Comment: @Renesis: I agree, some people need to double check their actions. :(

Comment: @Renesis I agree as well, this is weird!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know much about doing this, but I made you a Query to look for images in you posts through Data Explorer. Let me know if something's wrong with it!

http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/s/1376/find-posts-by-you-that-contain-images

Comment: Not so bad idea, I could probably just insert the host I'm using and also create ones that don't contain.

Comment: @TomWij Check the Query now, you can now look for a certain host as well.

Comment: @TomWij Updated the link! Use that one!